# How to parse and iterate to save information in dyanomodb with lamda in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

In order to save data from lamda to dynamodb,

```html
import json
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('table1')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
        readJson = json.dumps(event)
        parseMe = json.loads(readJson)
        table.put_item(
         Item={
            'webhook_ID': context.aws_request_id,
            'eventType': parseMe['body-json']["eventType"],
            'Name': parseMe['body-json']["Name"],
            'Id': parseMe['body-json']["Id"],
            'ReferenceId': parseMe['body-json']["ReferenceId"],
            'mock': parseMe['body-json']["mock"],
            'description': parseMe['body-json']["description"]
        })
        return {
        'status' : 200,
        'body': json.dumps('data has been received.'),
        'requestID' : context.aws_request_id
        }
```

In the above code, I am parsing each and every json attribute such as

> Name

,

> mock

where as I want to iterate it, as in future I might need to remove or add attributes in the json. This json attributes gets save in the table1 of dynamodb aws
Suggestion ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to iterate? Please share the value of `event` and be more clear on what you want to achieve.

Comment: yes, the events which will be in json format, needs to be iterate, then I can save it into the dynamodb

Comment: Can you share the value for `events`?

Comment: its json, {
  "Name": "Sobhit"
}

Comment: To iterate means to loop over something, I don't see why you need to iterate over a JSON payload? Is there an array inside `event` that you want to iterate on?

Comment: event gets save into the dynamodb, as per the event attributes as you can see in the  eventType': parseMe['body-json']["eventType"] , now in order to add more attributes or removing, either I need to add/remove new attributes into the lamda. But if I iterate, all the attributes will be captured into the db.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a dict like below:

```
for attr, value in my_dict.items():
        print(attr, value)
```

You can also just save the event as a JSON blob, assuming `webhook_ID` is your partiton key:

```
table.put_item(
         Item={
            'webhook_ID': context.aws_request_id,
            'event': parseMe
        })
```

Comment: dict should happen inside the table.put ?

Comment: No you want to define the item you want to save before adding it to table.put